# How can a non-integer value be used as the index of a (2D) list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If we would like to address a location in a 2D list in python with non-integer values, for example with a string in the form of a tuple, how can the indexing be handled?
I am using dictionary as a solution, but I am not sure if it is the best solution.

Exampe:

```
mylist = {'a1':{"('p1','p2')":10, "('p1','p3')":11}, 'a2':{"('p4','p5')":12, "('p4','p6')":13}}
```

and now:

```
mylist['a1']["('p1','p2')"] = 20
```

I think it is not an efficient solution. Any other solution please?

Comment: Why would regular indexing not work?

Comment: Isn't that just effectively a 3d list? i.e. `{'a1': {'p1': {'p2': 10, 'p3': 11}, ... }, ... }`

Comment: @kynnem Because I need the indices as the parameters of some other functions.

Comment: @MatsLindh No. Whole the tuple string is needed at once.

Comment: Can you explain your data a bit better (your actual data, not your current python representation)? What are a1, p1, p2 etc? What operations would you like to perform on them?

Comment: @PaulHankin They are the input parameters of a function. We need them as the indices to save the output of the function and use the output in an another function while knowing the parameters.

Comment: @PaulHankin These are the parameters of the function whose result is needed to be saved in a 2D array in a Dynamic programming problem.

Comment: @JRad But that's just a detail about how you use each dimension in the array - the structure is effectively three dimensional, since you have two dimensions inside what you now consider your second dimension.

Comment: @MatsLindh It it actually one dimension and one string and it has to be since the string "('p1','p2')" is one parameter for me.

Comment: Well, you're asking for a better solution, but none of the proposed solutions are acceptable because you're locked into using the structure you've already decided on. I'm not sure what you then hope to achieve by asking for contributions.

Comment: @MatsLindh Either me or you are misunderstood. You proposed a 3D solution. a1 works individually as a dimension, while the function will not result in solution with p1 or p2 individually. p1 and p2 both together are needed resources for a job to be done. without them together the function will not yield a value to be placed in the array. Please let be updated if I am misunderstood.

Comment: Which will be accessible when you iterate over the structure, and can be formatted before calling the function that expects it in a specific format - `for a_lvl, inner in data.items(): for first_key, innermost in inner.items(): for second_key, value in innermost.items(): call_other_function(first_key + ',' + second_key, value)`

Comment: A list can never be indexed by something else than an integer since it's a sequential container, not a key-value storage.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you're trying to make the second dimension tuple-shaped. So, what if you just turn the strings into tuples?

For example:

```
>>> mylist = {'a1': {('p1','p2'): 10, ('p1','p3'): 11}, 'a2': {('p4','p5'): 12, ('p4','p6'): 13}}
>>> mylist['a1'][('p1','p2')]
10
```

I cannot comment on your posts at this time because my reputation score is not enough. Oops. :)

Comment: I am new in stackoverflow. Actually, I don't know how to help you :|

Comment: No, I just want to help you. Don't worry about me. Can you explain your problem a bit more details in your post?

Comment: Please check the question's comments.

Comment: I did, but still not clear enough for me. Are p1 and p2 represent your location point?

Comment: And what do you mean by inefficient?

Comment: Using an string may easily cause an error if only a character is changed

Comment: '('p1','p')' is the column index.